# How to debug tslint `"no-use-before-declare"` setting being ignored by VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint, react-scripts

Update: I see now a message that was getting cleared by the dev server: "Warning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type infomation." This maps to the following issue: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/126 This is a duplicate of the above issue.

Scenario: I'm using VSCode with TSLint, with a custom `tslint.json`, in a project created with `create-react-scripts-ts` (and currently using `react-scripts-ts@2.4.0`).

The `tslint.json` entry, `"no-use-before-declare"` setting, is being ignored by VSCode (I have it set to `false`).

Question: How can I debug this?  (For example, where can I see what VSCode is reading to get its tslint settings? Perhaps somehow it is pointed at the wrong file, or there is some other override happening).

The StackOverflow editor won't let me paste the tslint file because it overbalances the post towards code content (!).  So here are a couple snippets:

````
```
{
  "extends": ["tslint-react"],
  "rules": {
    "align": [true, "parameters", "statements"],
    ...
    "no-use-before-declare": false,
  }
}
```
````

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `tslint.json` file?

Comment: Done (as much as possible) - thanks.

Comment: Can you not "debug" it by adding a violation in your code temporarily, and then enable the option to see you get a warning, then disable it again to confirm the warning goes?

Comment: Are other rules which are not set according to the defaults being applied?

Comment: @Fenton I think this is exactly the case- it is currently flagging an error, and he doesn't want it to.

Comment: (Updated): I *did* get a message in the vscode "Problems" pane: "file: severity: 'Error' message: 'Expected comma or closing brace'.  But tslinting still "works".

Comment: I imagine there is a problem with your JSON.  Try copying the contents of your `tslint.json` into a json linter and see if there are any errors you can fix.

Comment: Done; JSON checks out okay.

Comment: I see now a message that was getting cleared by the dev server: "Warning: The 'no-use-before-declare' rule requires type infomation."   This maps to the following issue: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/126  

Closing this question then as it is a duplicate of the above issue.